# Exist unique $f \in C([0, 1])$ such that $f(x) = \int_0^x K(x, y)\,f(y)\,dy + g(x)?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K \in C([0, 1] \times [0, 1])$ and $g \in C([0, 1])$. Does there exist a unique $f \in C([0, 1])$ such that, for all $x \in [0, 1]$, we have$$f(x) = \int_0^x K(x, y)\,f(y)\,dy + g(x)?$$

Comment: This seems like a classic application of the Banach fixed point theorem; in particular, you will want to control $\left | \int_0^x K(x,y) (f(y)-h(y)) dy \right |$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\int_0^x K(x,y)f(y)\,dy+g(x)$$
Taking derivatives both sides with respect to $x$ we get

$$f'(x)=K(x,x)f(x)+g'(x)$$
$$f'(x)-K(x,x)f(x)=g'(x)$$

Let $\mu(x)=\exp(\int -K(x,x)\,dx)$ and multiply both sides by it
$$\mu(x)f'(x)-K(x,x)\mu(x)f(x)=\mu(x)g'(x)$$

Notice that $-K(x,x)\mu(x)=\mu'(x)$ so:
$$\mu(x)f'(x)+\mu'(x)f(x)=\mu(x)g'(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\mu(x)f(x))=\mu(x)g'(x)$$
$$\mu(x)f(x)=\int_0^x \mu(y)g'(y)\,dy+C$$
$$f(x)=\frac{\int_0^x \mu(y)g'(y)\,dy+C}{\mu(x)}$$

Then we find $C$ from the relation:

$$f(0)=\int_0^0K(x,y)f(y)\,dy+g(0)=g(0)$$

So $f$ must be unique.